# Circuit to bypass switch

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi, circuit-design

I am looking to activate a switch on a sensor platform I have, via a GPIO(3.3v) pin on a Raspberry PI. The board itself is powered by the Pi, via USB.
The problem is, I have very limited electronics experience, so I'm hoping someone can advise me.

The [switch](http://img.diytrade.com/cdimg/2050561/32196586/0/1365323987/6_6_SMD_Push_button_Tact_switch.jpg) looks quite easy to bypass if I solder to the underside of the board. I was thinking of something like [Using an NPN transistor](http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits), but would like some expert advice before I attempt anything.

One more thing, would you advise me to put some form of GPIO protection circuit into the design?

**Edit**
Testing the sensor board, it appears one of the pins on the switch is grounded, the other is to some pin on one of the IC's

**Edit #2**
Voltage across the switch is 5.07v when open, and ~500μA current when closed

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjqG2K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can it be done.. of course, But you would need to add a schematic, show voltages currents etc. Details matter...

Comment: Schematic of which, the sensor board? I dont have it, but I can certainly create an abstraction of the circuit I'd like.
As for voltages/currents, which ones? The voltage & current across the switch?

Comment: And apologies on the details. I know they matter, I'm just unsure on what details matter :\

Comment: Things like, is one end connected to ground, or the plus side of the battery, is the switch just carrying a signal, are all important details to know before you can decide on a bypass circuit.

Comment: Assuming you got that all the right way round, i.e. the arrow on Q1 goes to ground, that circuit should work, yes.

Comment: I've updated the schematic with the correct layout. Activating the switch, grounds the IC pin. Is the bypass circuit still correct now?

Comment: nope transistor is upside down the way your drew it.

Comment: does it have internal pullup? NPN-E goes to gnd, not C.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the circuit with your comment. I've also added voltage/current information. Any particular transistor recommended?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use an NPN trasnistor to bypass a switch if you know that the switch is connected in the circuit in a way that an NPN transistor will work.

If you don't know how the switch is connectected, you should probably use a small relay.  The relay contacts will be totally isolated from the circuit controlling the relay, so won't interfere with the operation of the original circuit.

Comment: I have updated the schematic with the switch configuration, and my proposed circuit

Comment: Your drawing hurts my head!  We normally place the ground wire at the bottom of the drawing.  If the transistor's emitter connects to the sensor board's ground as well as to the Pi's ground, that should work.

Comment: Sorry :\ Its almost like this isn't my day job